# Spartacus 4 - How to extend default Storefront theme?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I tried basic primary color change in Spartacus 4.0.1 but it seems to be overwritten by the default styling. Followed the guide: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/

Is there a work around for this or is it fixed in newer versions?

Here's my code
*mystore/src/styles.scss*:

```
$primary: green;
$font-weight-normal: 600;

$styleVersion: 4.0;
@import "~@spartacus/styles/index";

:root {
    --cx-color-primary: green;
}
```

[screenshot showing my style is being overwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leUe4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem today. Have a look inside your **angular.json** file inside the root folder. There is a section that defines the styles that are loaded. For me this looked something like this:

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss"
   "src/styles/spartacus/user.scss",
   "src/styles/spartacus/organization.scss",
   "src/styles/spartacus/checkout.scss",
   "src/styles/spartacus/cart.scss",
],
```

I noticed that inside the **user.scss** and all other imports the standard **@spartacus/styles** library is imported at the top. So everything you do in your **styles.scss** is overwritten again by these imports.

My approach for now was to put the **styles.scss** at the end. So nothing is overwritten.

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles/spartacus/user.scss",
  "src/styles/spartacus/organization.scss",
  "src/styles/spartacus/checkout.scss",
  "src/styles/spartacus/cart.scss",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

To me it seems like a bug that the order is like this. Might report it later.

Comment: Yes, you're right @timoblume. I re-ordered and it's working now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and recommended way to override basic primary colors, as of version 4.0, is by changing the compiled values of the CSS variables. But change them inside a CSS `body` selector, instead of a `:root` selector.

Example of *storefrontapp/src/styles.scss* file:

```
$useLatestStyles: true;

@import '@spartacus/styles';
@import '@spartacus/styles/scss/theme/santorini';

body {
  --cx-color-primary: #a7fff6;
  --cx-color-seconday: #8aa39b;
  --cx-color-text: #5c6f68;
  --cx-color-background: #95d9c3;
  --cx-color-dark: #a4f9c8;
}
```